# Change background color customize C#

Tags: c#

i want to use the F1EFE2 color in Window App form background.how to write the code in C#.

Comment: which form? web or windows app? give us some more background (color) :)

Comment: See my updated answer. you can use .FromHtml() inplace of .ConvertFromString()

Answer (score 5):

If you are intersted in `System.Windows.Media.Color` you can use this snippet (make you sure you added `System.Widnows.Media` namespace):

```
Color backGroundColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#F1EFE2");
```

If you are interested in `System.Drawing.Color` you can use ColorConverter from `System.Drawing` namespace:

```
ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter();
Color backGroundColor = cc.ConvertFromString("#F1EFE2");
```

Comment: (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#F1EFE2");
what need to do now error

Comment: (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#F1EFE2")"ERROR An object reference is required for the non-static field,method or property'system.compontmodel.typeconverter.ConvertFromString("")

Comment: .ConvertFromString(string) don't have.what need to do?

Comment: @stataa123, ok. you've tried to use ColorConverted from System.Drawing it seems, I mentioned the one from System.Windows.Media. I've added code snippets for both cases.

Comment: i have only system.Window.Form.Don't have the System.Windows.Media.Color,System.Drawing.Color.

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming your form id is form1, now in style tag use this:

```
#form1{
    background-color:#f1efe2;
}
```

FOR windows app use this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Media
Color bgcolor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#f1efe2");
```

(this assumes an RGB value)

or

```
Color bgcolor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f1efe2");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do call the using System.window.Media.I using now VB 2008.

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net in codebehind:

```
Form1.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#f1efe2");
```

side note: better to use class instead of style.

Ok winforms. First convert to rgb then do this:

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(241, 239, 226);
```

Here's a convertor: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

Comment: i want to ask any question.i want to read form xml data file.how to write.

Comment: That's a whole separate question. You should open a new one. Make sure you do your research and attempt it before asking the question though.
Also, don't forget to uprate/accept answers that you think are correct, otherwise people will be hesitant to answer.